# All tests are being considered "timed out" but my mutation score is 100%

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, stryker

I'm trying to run mutation testing with Stryker on my project which uses JEST to run unit testing.

I didn't get any errors, but all the tests are getting the “timeout” status, however, my mutation score is 100%.

Is this correct? Can I accept this as a good result? Or that something wrong happened?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Jqy.png)

I installed the Stryker library, and ran the command "npx stryker run"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.